# ExpressJs - Finding records matching route parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I have been building out a tagging system for my ExpressJS application and I have been able to create my routing to pick up on the individual tags that are used for my record, but the issue I am running into is trying to display content associated with the selected tag. For instance a record has a tag "Mouse", when clicked the route correctly goes to `/tag/mouse`, but I'm not sure if I should use a loop within my template to display only those values or if I should really be using a method within my route. I'm currently using nothing and the value being displayed on the tag page is `undefined`. I have a feeling the route method is what I am looking for.

Here is the main focus of my routes file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');

    var blogDB = require('../config/blogDB.js');
    var Blogpost = require('./models/blogModel.js');
    var paginate = require('express-paginate');
    var http = require('http');
    var path = require('path');
    var aws = require('aws-sdk');
    router.route('/admin/posts/create')

        // START POST method
            .post(function(req, res) {

                console.log("New instance");
                console.log(req.body.tags);
                var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

                blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
                blogpost.featureImage = req.body.featureImage; // set the blog image
                blogpost.blogUrl = blogpost.title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,"-");
                blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
                blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // set the tagline
                blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
                blogpost.category = req.body.category; // set the category
                blogpost.tags = req.body.tags.trim().split(","); // set the tags

                    //Save Blog Post
                    blogpost.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            res.send(err);

                        res.redirect(303, '/'); //NEEDS TO BE CHANGED
                    });

            }) // END POST method


            .get(isLoggedIn, function(req, res, blogpost) {
                res.render('pages/blogpost-create', {
                  blogpost : blogpost
                });
            });

    function getSearchCriteria(params) {
          return {
              blogUrl: params.blogpost_blogUrl
          };
    }


    router.route('/blog/:blogpost_blogUrl')

        .get(function (req, res) {
             var searchCriteria = getSearchCriteria(req.params);
             Blogpost.findOne(searchCriteria, function (err, blogpost) {
                 if (err)
                     res.send(err);
                 res.render('pages/blogpost', {
                     blogpost: blogpost
                 })
             })
         })
         .put(function (req, res) {
             var searchCriteria = getSearchCriteria(req.params);
             var updated = getBlogpostUpdate(req.body)
             Blogpost.findOneAndUpdate(searchCriteria, updated, function (err, updated) {
                 if (err)
                     res.send(err);


                 res.json({ message: 'Blog updated.' });
             });
         })
         .delete(function (req, res) {
             var searchCriteria = getSearchCriteria(req.params);
             Blogpost.findOneAndRemove(searchCriteria, function (err, removed) {
                 if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                 res.json({ message: 'Successfully deleted' });
             });
         });


    router.get('/tag/:blogpost_tags', function(req, res, next) {
        Blogpost.paginate({}, req.query.page, req.query.limit, function(err, pageCount, blogpost, itemCount) {
                if (err) return next(err)
                  if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                  res.format({
                                html: function() {
                                    res.render('pages/tag', {
                                        blogpost: blogpost,
                                        pageCount: pageCount,
                                        itemCount: itemCount
                                    })
                                },
                                json: function() {

                                    res.json({
                                        object: 'blogpost',
                                        has_more: paginate.hasNextPages(req)(pageCount),
                                        data: blogpost
                                    })
                                }
                            }); // END res.format(html, json)
                }, {sortBy: {'date': -1} } ); // END Blogpost.paginate
        });
```

Model:

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;



var BlogPostSchema  = new Schema({
        title: String,
        featureImage: String,
        blogUrl: String,
        author: String,
        tagline: String,
        category: String,
        content: String,
        tags: { type: Array, lowercase: true },
        date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
});

BlogPostSchema.post('init', function (post) {
    var date = new Date(post.date || Date.now() );
    post.dateString = date.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();

});

BlogPostSchema.plugin( mongoosePaginate );

var Blogpost = mongoose.model("Blogpost", BlogPostSchema);



module.exports = mongoose.model('Blogpost', BlogPostSchema);
```

Tag page (EJS):

```
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <%= blogpost.tags %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you already have the objects loaded in your frontend section, there's no need to fetch that data again. But if you don't have all records associated with the tag, you have no alternative: you have to make another request to your server side. Since you're using `express-paginate` and `mongoose-paginate`, they'll handle the amount of records you're going to fetch on each request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return dynamically created .js file when route is hit in ExpressJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810107/return-dynamically-created-js-file-when-route-is-hit-in-expressjs)