# Return dynamically created .js file when route is hit in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, express

I am building an ExpressJS app and I want it to return a dynamically created .js file when the route is hit. This route will be used by an html `<script>` tag. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why a file? You can build a variable with the code in it. If you create it as a function, you should be able to run it on the client.

Answer (score 1):

You need it to be a file on the client side does not mean that it has to be a file on server side as well.
Write a route for the file you want and return the dynamically created script from the handler.

```
router.get("/public/js/notafile.js", function(req, res) {
    // This doesn't have to be a one liner
    res.send("function(){console.log('yey')}");
});
```

You can use a template, like underscore template or otherwise a template file and replace the placeholders to generate complex functions dynamically.

If you are serving a file that the client expects is under your /public folder you may want to bind this before your static binding. I. E. Before:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```